# How To Make Laravel DB Query Result is Cached To Variable For Handling Simultaneous Same SQL Query To Reduce Number Of Same SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a DB class in my non laravel application. The code is like the following. It handle SQL query and store the result to the $query_cache so  whenever another same query executed in current page request it will send the data from $query_cache without executing mysql query. It
s gain better performance and reduce sql query.

```
private $query_cache=array();
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

        if((strpos(strtolower($sql), 'select')) !== false) {
         if(array_key_exists(md5('db-engine'.$sql),$this->query_cache ))
         {
            return $this->query_cache[md5('db-engine'.$sql)]; 
         }
        }
          $result = $this->adaptor->query($sql, $params);         
          $this->query_cache[md5('db-engine'.$sql)]=$result;
          return $result;

    }
```

So what it should be done in Laravel framework?

Comment: I think that you need `remember` method. - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache

Answer (score 0):

you would cache your model instead of your query

Comment: Note: I don't think to 'cache' to file or using memcache, Just I wan't to save the query result on certain variable so next same sql query will take data from that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Cache https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache

```
$value = Cache::get(md5('db-engine'.$sql), function() {
    return DB::table(...)->get();
});

return $value;
```